# Should we create a test html file similar to actual file , while writing unit tests for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am using 2 sets of radiobuttons, a text field and a submit button in my html page. such that after entering data in the fields and clicking the button a jquery ajax function is called to post the data(my use case is not to reload the page). How to write unit tests for this javascript file also should i create a test html file with all the above said fields?

my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="form">
<div id="buttons">
<p>Please select your gender:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="10"> 10<br>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="20"> 20<br>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="40"> 40<br>  

<p>Please select your age:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="30"> 30<br>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="60"> 60<br>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="100"> 100<br>  
</div>
Text Value: <input type="text" name="Text Value" id="text"><br>
<button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>

my JS code:
var inputVal = document.getElementById("text").value;
var value= $("input:radio[name=number]:checked").val();
var data = inputVal+" "+value;
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
data = {"data" : JSON.stringify(data)};
button.onclick = function() {
$.ajax({
  url: '/url',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function() {
    console.log( 'worked');
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log( 'something went wrong');
  }
});
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that your code is working in the first place, because you create your data outside of the click event

Comment: do you know the solution ? if yes guide me.

Comment: Sure - Move lines 1-5 (`var inputVal...` - `data = {"data"...`) into the `onclick` function

Comment: that being said , can you also answer about writing a test js file and structure of test html

Comment: No, I know nothing about unit tests. Sorry :)

Comment: well the actual question is about that :)